# Permission Boundary IAM role denying attaching administrator policy

Tags: json, amazon-iam

Can anyone point me how to accomplish the instruction below. I am trying to find it playing with roles and policy but I can't find any way to accomplish a granular approach to deny attaching administrator policy and maintaining other IAM rights.

*Set an IAM permission boundary on the development IAM role that explicitly denies attaching the administrator policy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine multiple conditions to achieve this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IAMPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAttachAdministratorPolicy",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::012345678912:policy/MyPermissionBoundary"
        },
        "ArnEquals": {
          "iam:PolicyARN": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(You would need to update the PB ARN mentioned in the policy)

Note that this might not handle other edge cases where a malicious user could potentially attach `AdministratorAccess` to something else and escalate their privileges (e.g. via a Lambda function or container maybe?).